# How can i fix timezone issue while using date format in moment.js?

Tags: datetime, timezone, momentjs, date-format, moment-timezone

This is my input date ,
`let inputDate = '2021-01-15T11:22:10.000Z'`.
I want to change the date format to `MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss`
For that i used following i used moment.js . This is my code,

`moment(inputDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss') = 01/15/2021 16:52:10`

After formatting the date i am getting the date with timezone added.How can i get the exact time in MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss format ?

I tried the following as well;

```
moment(inputDate).local(true).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss')
moment(inputDate).utcOffset(330).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss')
moment(inputDate).utcOffset(0).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss')
moment(inputDate).utcOffset("+05:30").format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss')
moment(inputDate).utcOffset("-05:30").format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss')
```

Please help me to figure out the issue .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should tell moment that the date you provide is in UTC. You can achieve this by using `utc()` function:

```
moment.utc(inputDate)
```

If you format after `utc()`, you will see the date in UTC timezone:

```
moment.utc(inputDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss')
```

```js
let inputDate = '2021-01-15T11:22:10.000Z';

console.log(moment.utc(inputDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```